# 'Input string was not in correct format' error VB

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, error-handling

I am trying to write to an Access database from textboxes in my main form. But when I start my program I get this error for the 'SubTotal' textbox even though I have tried changing the datatype.

The data type on my access database for this field is: Number > Decima.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
    Dim str = "Insert into Orders(OrderNo, Subtotal, VAT, FullAmount, Discount, CustomerID, Employees) Values (@OrderNo, @SubTotal, @VAT, @FullAmount, @Discount, @CustomerID, @Employees);"
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString),
            cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, connection)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@OrderNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtorderno.Text)
            .Add("@SubTotal", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtsubtotal.Text)
            .Add("@VAT", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtvat.Text)
            .Add("@FullAmount", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txttotal.Text)
            .Add("@Discount", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtdiscount.Text)
            .Add("@CustomerID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = (ComboBox2.Text)
            .Add("@Employees", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        End With
        connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

[image]

Comment: That's most likely an error from `Convert.ToInt32` or `Convert.ToDecimal`. Use `Int32.TryParse` and `Decimal.TryParse` instead.

Comment: What exactly is the content of txtsubtotal.Text.  Have you got some unexpected formatting and/or currency symbols?  And slightly off topic,  Seems odd, SubTotal is a Decimal yet vat, FullAmount & Discount are all Integers.

Comment: @user9938 The OP can't simply substitute the `TryParse` methods. `TryParse` returns a Boolean which would not be the desired result.

Comment: @Mary: I never stated or insinuated that other code changes wouldn't be required-I merely suggested that they be used. By not providing additional information, it was my intention that the OP look up the documentation on how to use each of them.

Comment: @user9938 Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: @Hursey Subtotal is basically the integer value of the order placed. I guess it could also be in decimals hence I wrote decimals. The rest are integers because I was experimenting with changing the datatype to see which one works. It started giving me an error on Subtotal, even though in database decimal is the datatype.

Comment: @user9938 I'm not sure how I'd use that. It gives me an error when I put it in.